# d3 merge a nested selection

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Given the following code which calls the `update` function which creates 4 nodes with a circle and text element nested in a `g` element, waits 500ms, then calls the function again with updated data:

```
var data1 = [
  { x: 10, y: 10, text: "A" },
  { x: 30, y: 30, text: "B" },
  { x: 50, y: 50, text: "C" },
  { x: 70, y: 70, text: "D" }
];

var data2 = [
  { x: 30, y: 10, text: "X" },
  { x: 50, y: 30, text: "Y" },
  { x: 70, y: 50, text: "Z" },
  { x: 90, y: 70, text: "W" }
];


var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");

update(data1);
setTimeout(function() { update(data2); }, 500);

function update(data) {

  var nodes = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(data);

  var nodesUpdate = nodes
      .attr("class", "node update")

  var nodesEnter = nodes.enter();

  var node = nodesEnter.append("g")
      .attr("class", "node enter")

  node
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return  "translate("+d.x+","+d.y+")"; });

  node.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 10)
      .style("opacity", 0.2);

  node.append("text")
      .text(function(d) { return  d.text; });
}
```

With the code as it is the second call has no effect, because everything is set in the enter selection. I'm trying to make it so I can call `update` with new data, and change properties on both the enter and update selections, without duplicating code. I can achieve this for top-level elements (ie the `g` elements) using `merge`, by making this change:

```
node
  .merge(nodesUpdate)
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return  "translate("+d.x+","+d.y+")"; });
```

Now the nodes update their position after 500ms. However, I haven't been able to figure out how to update the text element. If I do `nodes.selectAll("text")` I end up with nested data, which doesn't work.

I've scoured the following docs to try and figure this out:

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218

https://github.com/d3/d3-selection

https://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should just be `nodes.select` when dealing with a subselection.

Here's a quick refactor with comments and clearer variable names:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var data1 = [{
      x: 10,
      y: 10,
      text: "A"
    }, {
      x: 30,
      y: 30,
      text: "B"
    }, {
      x: 50,
      y: 50,
      text: "C"
    }, {
      x: 70,
      y: 70,
      text: "D"
    }];

    var data2 = [{
      x: 30,
      y: 10,
      text: "X"
    }, {
      x: 50,
      y: 30,
      text: "Y"
    }, {
      x: 70,
      y: 50,
      text: "Z"
    }, {
      x: 90,
      y: 70,
      text: "W"
    }];

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");

    update(data1);
    setTimeout(function() {
      update(data2);
    }, 500);

    function update(data) {

      var nodesUpdate = svg.selectAll(".node")
        .data(data); // UPDATE SELECTION

      var nodesEnter = nodesUpdate.enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "node"); // ENTER THE Gs
         
      nodesEnter.append("text"); // APPEND THE TEXT
      
      nodesEnter.append("circle") // APPEND THE CIRCLE
        .attr("r", 10)
        .style("opacity", 0.2);
      
      var nodesEnterUpdate = nodesEnter.merge(nodesUpdate); // UPDATE + ENTER

      nodesEnterUpdate // MOVE POSITION
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
        });

      nodesEnterUpdate.select("text") // SUB-SELECT THE TEXT
        .text(function(d) {
          return d.text;
        });
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: One thing I'm still confused about: I thought selection.select only selects the first of the matching elements. How is it managing to grab all the text elements here?

Comment: @anderspitman, it grabs the first one in the subselection.  It's still iterating the parent selection.  `nodesEnterUpdate` is a collection of `g`, foreach `g` get me the first `text` and update it.

Comment: I think that was the key piece of understanding I was missing this whole time. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Without refactoring a lot of your code, the simplest solution is using a key in the data function, followed by an "exit" selection:

```
var nodes = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(data, d=> d.text);

nodes.exit().remove();
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var data1 = [{
  x: 10,
  y: 10,
  text: "A"
}, {
  x: 30,
  y: 30,
  text: "B"
}, {
  x: 50,
  y: 50,
  text: "C"
}, {
  x: 70,
  y: 70,
  text: "D"
}];

var data2 = [{
  x: 30,
  y: 10,
  text: "X"
}, {
  x: 50,
  y: 30,
  text: "Y"
}, {
  x: 70,
  y: 50,
  text: "Z"
}, {
  x: 90,
  y: 70,
  text: "W"
}];


var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");

update(data1);
setTimeout(function() {
  update(data2);
}, 500);

function update(data) {

  var nodes = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(data, d => d.text);

  nodes.exit().remove();

  var nodesUpdate = nodes
    .attr("class", "node update")

  var nodesEnter = nodes.enter();

  var node = nodesEnter.append("g")
    .attr("class", "node enter")

  node
    .merge(nodesUpdate)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });

  node.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 10)
    .style("opacity", 0.2);

  node.append("text")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.text;
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

This will create a *different* "enter" selection. If, on the other hand, you want to get the data bound to the "update" selection, you'll have to refactor your code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm confused by this code. I don't see how it can work. Since you're using a key function to only access the `text` for each datum, how are the x and y ever available? Also, why is the exit necessary?

Comment: My answer is not exactly what you're looking for: by using the key function, it's creating a new enter selection every time you update the data, thus the need of an exit selection. I'm busy now, but I'll soon post a solution relying on the update selection.

Comment: anderspitman never mind, I was about to write a solution using the update selection but I'm seeing that @Mark [just posted it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42736430/5768908), have a look at his answer. So, in a nuthsell: in my answer, I'm creating a new enter selection for the new data and removing the old selection. In his answer there is just one enter selection, the elements stay on the chart and their data change in the update selection. His answer is what you want.